# Как выполнить команду PowerShell в Python?

Tags: python, powershell

Допустим, что у меня есть обычная команда PowerShell, выводящая информацию о сетевых интерфейсах в текстовый файл: `ipconfig | Out-File -FilePath E:\PowerShellLogs\Primer.txt`
Выполняя ее в командной строке PowerShell всё работает.
Теперь мне нужно написать программу на Python, которая просто выполнит эту команду powershell, после ее запуска
Как это написать?
Попробовал написать это, ошибок после выполнения нет, но ничего не произошло

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe','ipconfig | Out-File -FilePath E:\PowerShellLogs\PrimerRabotiIzPython.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `subprocess.run()` с аргументом в виде списка. Также не забывайте экранировать слеши или использовать r-строки.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', r'ipconfig | Out-File -FilePath E:\PowerShellLogs\PrimerRabotiIzPython.txt'])
```

Answer (score -1):

subprocess.**Popen**?
Уберите P..

Comment: Смотрите документацию: [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen)